# having trouble calling \regex_match

Tags: expl3, l3regex

This works as expected:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\ExplSyntaxOn
  % USE X instead of \space for a space.
  \catcode`\X=\active
  \defX{\space }

  % \mycheck:nnn <regex> <string to test against regex> <end of error message>
  \cs_set:Npn \mycheck:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \regex_match:nnTF
      {#1}
      {#2}
      { \typeout{Match.} }
      {
        \typeout{NoXmatch.}
        \typeout{ItXshouldXbeX#3.}
      }
  }
  \mycheck:nnn {\A(true|false)\Z} {true}    {`true'XorX`false'}
  \mycheck:nnn {\A(true|false)\Z} {false}   {`true'XorX`false'}
  \mycheck:nnn {\A(true|false)\Z} {neither} {`true'XorX`false'}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

I would like to use something where I can call it with, for example,

```
\def\cs{true}  % or false or something else
\newcheck {\A(true|false)\Z} {cs} {`true'XorX`false'}
```

and the value of \cs is checked.  I want to use cs name and the value of \cs in an improved error message.  In practice the regex, cs, and the end of the error message will all change.  Sometimes the regex will not check for one of several values.

Comment: Why are you using `X` for a space?

Comment: What's the definition of `\newcheck`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass as second argument a csname, you need a variant.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% \mycheck:nnn <regex> <string to test against regex> <end of error message>
\cs_new_protected:Nn \mycheck:nnn
  {
    \regex_match:nnTF
      {#1}
      {#2}
      { \typeout{Match.} }
      {
        \typeout{No~match.}
        \typeout{It~should~be~#3.}
      }
  }
\mycheck:nnn {\A(true|false)\Z} {true}    {`true'~or~`false'}
\mycheck:nnn {\A(true|false)\Z} {false}   {`true'~or~`false'}
\mycheck:nnn {\A(true|false)\Z} {neither} {`true'~or~`false'}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \mycheck:nnn { nv }

\def\cs{true}

\mycheck:nvn {\A(true|false)\Z} {cs} {`true'~or~`false'}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\stop
```

The relevant console output is

```
Match.
Match.
No match.
It should be `true' or `false'.
Match.
```

The `X` part is definitely to be avoided: in order to get a space you type `~` as in the code above.

Comment: egreg: It works except I don't know how to get the string "cs" inside the function. Should I use a wrapper function to get it?

Comment: @MarkSenn Sorry, but I don’t understand: using `\mycheck:nvn` *is* adding a wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with to print control sequence name and control sequence value in the error message:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\ExplSyntaxOn
  % \mycheck:nnn <regex> <string to test against regex> <end of error message>
  \cs_set:Npn \mycheck:nnn #1#2#3
    {
      \regex_match:nnTF
        {#1}
        {#2}
        { \typeout{Match.} }
        {
          \typeout{No~match.}
          % \remember contains the `~'
          \typeout{\c_backslash_str\remember is~`#2'.}
          \typeout{It~should~be~#3.}
          \stop
        }
    }

  \cs_generate_variant:Nn \mycheck:nnn { nv }

  \cs_set:Npn \Check:nnn #1#2#3
    {
      \def\remember{#2~}
      \mycheck:nvn {\A(true|false)\Z} {#2} {`true'~or~`false'}
    }

  \def\cs{true}
  \Check:nnn {\A(true|false)\Z} {cs} {`true'~or~`false'}
  \def\cs{false}
  \Check:nnn {\A(true|false)\Z} {cs} {`true'~or~`false'}
  \def\cs{neither}
  \Check:nnn {\A(true|false)\Z} {cs} {`true'~or~`false'}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I originally made X'  an active character for '\space ' in my minimal example because '~~' didn't produce two spaces in a \typeout.  (In my non-minimal example I use a Unicode U+25AF).